# How to relate a Drupal user using a custom Content Type with a common field using Views module?

Tags: views

I am trying to use the [Views](https://www.drupal.org/project/views) module, either via the UI, or using a hook offered by the Views module, to select a Drupal user using a value from a custom Content Type named *record* that I defined. Let me explain further:

The Drupal user has a field named 'field_usr_banner_id' that holds a value that matches the same value that would be available in the Content Type named 'field_cvsoptout_studentid'. So essentially I would like this to happen, explained via pseudo-code.

Drupal user has a banner Id of '222222'
Record has a student Id of '222222'

```
SELECT * FROM User INNER JOIN Record's Student Id ON Drupal User's BannerId
```

See, when adding a new content type of 'record', I specify a few fields, and one of those fields is the student id. I would like to configure views so that it knows it can reference a Drupal user with the student id, and if a Drupal user does exist, to return the first, lastname, and banner id. If a Drupal user does not exist, to just display the banner id.

I'm going through this trouble because it's possible that when a record is created, the Drupal user does not exist. Now, I could specify the user information when the record exists, but if a Drupal user is ever created in the future with a banner Id matching the record's student Id, the record would not display correctly.

Is this even possible to do in Drupal with the Views module? Is there an easier way of doing this?